# Why can't I import a Python dependency even if it is declared as a runtime dependency in package.xml?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, package.xml, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the following dependencies in my `package.xml`

```
<buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>

<build_depend>message_filters</build_depend>
<build_depend>rosbag</build_depend>
<build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
<build_depend>tf</build_depend>

<build_export_depend>message_filters</build_export_depend>
<build_export_depend>rosbag</build_export_depend>
<build_export_depend>rospy</build_export_depend>
<build_export_depend>tf</build_export_depend>

<exec_depend>message_filters</exec_depend>
<exec_depend>rosbag</exec_depend>
<exec_depend>rospy</exec_depend>
<exec_depend>tf</exec_depend>

<exec_depend>python-h5py</exec_depend>
<exec_depend>python-opencv</exec_depend>
<exec_depend>python-pandas</exec_depend>
<exec_depend>python-tqdm</exec_depend>
```

I have done `rosdep install my_package` and `catkin build` inside my workspace (and I got no error). However, whenever I try to do `pip list` or to import any of the Python dependencies I specified above, such as Pandas or OpenCV, I get an `ImportError` or I don't see them in the list. I want to use those Python dependencies in my scripts or source files inside `my_package`.

If the correct way of specifying Python dependencies is by specifying them in `<exec_depend>` (see e.g. [http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/python_module_dependencies.html)](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/python_module_dependencies.html)), then why can't I see `pandas` when doing `pip list`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333596/why-can%27t-i-import-a-python-dependency-even-if-it-is-declared-as-a-runtime-dependency-in-package.xml?/) by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 372 on 2019-09-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-22**:
What is the output of `which python` and `python --version`?

---

Edit: I doubt `<build_export_depend>rospy</build_export_depend>` is needed: `rospy` is a pure Python package. It cannot be a `build_export_depend` as there are no headers for other (C++) packages to depend on/include.

In general: I would guess 99% of Python dependencies would be only `exec_depend`s.

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2019-09-22**:
The output of the first command is `/home/me/catkin_ws/src/my_package/venv/bin/python` and of the second is `Python 2.7.15+`. I am inside a virtual environment, as you can see.

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2019-09-22**:
Regarding the `<build_export_depend>rospy</build_export_depend>`, it was added automatically when I used `catkin create pkg --catkin-deps rospy rosbag tf message_filters -- my_package`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-22**:
Yes, it does that. But that is just because there is no support for Python packages *specifically*. You can remove all dependencies other than `exec_depend`s from your manifest. Unless you have a mixed C++/Python package, that is.

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2019-09-22**:
@gvdhoorn How do I know which packages contain only Python code? Now, you told me that `rospy` only needs to be specified as a `exec_depend`, because it only contains Python code. In general, though, is there a way of knowing whether a dependency only contains Python code, without having to look at the source code?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-22**:
"only contain Python code" is just a shortcut.

`build_export_depend` is only used for telling packages that depend on you that they also (transitively) depend on your exported dependencies.

So if you have a header (C++) that includes `a.hpp`, which comes from package `pkg_a`, then in order for dependants of your package to be able to include *your* headers, they must also have `pkg_a`, or your headers will fail compilation with a `cannot find 'pkg_a/a.hpp'`.

Python is not a compiled language, so this cannot happen. Ergo: no `build_export_depend`s.

Unless you have a mixed C++/Python package, have C++/C bindings or are doing other more complex things.

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2019-09-22**:
@gvdhoorn However, you did not answer my specific question above about "how do I determine whether a package only needs to be specified as `exec_depend`, only contains Python code, or is or not required at build time. Maybe I will ask another question on the website.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-22**:
You really need me to explain you how to determine that a package "only contains Python code"?

There is no single command or fool proof way to see that from anything other than by looking at all the sources that make up the package.

Also: you add `build_export_depend`s to *your* package. As you are -- presumably -- the author of your own source code, you should know whether you are `#include`-ing anything from your dependencies in your own headers. You should also know whether you are creating a Python-only package.

`build_export_depend`s communicate to your users which packages *your* package is using. Not the other way around.

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2019-09-22**:
@gvdhoorn Well, what would happen if a new version `rospy` contained C++ code? Then this would break some code. There should be a way of tagging packages as Python-only, etc., packages, so that this can be looked up easily, and people would know how to specify the dependencies. ROS is one of the worst pieces of software that I've ever seen, given its quite unnecessary complexity and bad design. I hope that ROS2 will improve all these points.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-22**:\

> ROS is one of the worst pieces of software that I've ever seen, given its quite unnecessary complexity and bad design.

I would not make such blanket statements without being aware of the history that made some of these design choices necessary.

> I hope that ROS2 will improve all these points.

Why "hope"? If you have concrete suggestions to improve things, contribute. That way you can make sure it will be better than what you now consider "unnecessarily complex and bad[ly] design[ed]".

It's a community project. Without community contributions it will not go into the direction a community member/the community will want. It will go into the direction the contributors want it to. Which may not be what you want.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-22**:\

> Well, what would happen if a new version `rospy` contained C++ code? Then this would break some code. There should be a way of tagging packages as Python-only, etc., packages, so that this can be looked up easily, and people would know how to specify the dependencies.

Please read my comment again: `build_export_depend` says something about *your* package.

If your package is a Python-only package (read: *your* code, not your dependencies), then *you* don't need to list any `build_export_depend`s.

If your package contains source code that is compiled, uses an inclusion system *and* requires dependants to have access to resources you include (again: in *your* source code), and those resources need to be around at *build time*, only then do you list them as `build_export_depend`s.

I have the feeling you believe you need to check all your dependencies and then state whether they should be `build_export_depend`s. You don't.

If you cannot `#include` it, it cannot be an export depend.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-22**:
Additionally:

> Well, what would happen if a new version `rospy` contained C++ code? Then this would break some code

if/when that happens, that would be a breaking change.

Those would not be introduced without ample communication and a tick-tock approach.

If such things change, yes, it may break packages. But that is why breaking changes are typically handled with care.

This would be no different from breaking changes in any other software product or project, so is not ROS specific.

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2019-09-22**:
@gvdhoorn Ok, thanks! Now, I understand which dependencies I have to specify in `build_export_depend`. However, to specify a dependency as a build one, I still need to look at the source code of those dependencies, but this is a drag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> The output of the first command is `/home/me/catkin_ws/src/my_package/venv/bin/python` and of the second is `Python 2.7.15+`. I am inside a virtual environment, as you can see.

This is most likely the cause of you not being able to `import` the packages listed in the package manifest: `rosdep` will use your OS' package manager -- which in the case of Ubuntu (and Debian) would be `apt` -- to install the system dependencies that you've listed in your package's manifest.

For `python-pandas` for instance, it would lookup the rosdep rule for that key ([here](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/9e7027a8124a99154ee647839f8517ba2d0013a9/rosdep/python.yaml#L2629-L2634)) and resolve it to `python-pandas` (in this case the `rosdep` key resolves to the same Ubuntu/Debian package name, but that is a coincidence).

It would then ask `apt` to `install` the `python-pandas` Debian package. On Ubuntu (and Debian), that would result in the Python 2 version of that package getting installed in the default system location: `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas`. There is also a Python 3 version of the `pandas` rosdep key ([here](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/9e7027a8124a99154ee647839f8517ba2d0013a9/rosdep/python.yaml#L5133-L5137)), but that wouldn't change what happens (it would just install the Python 3 version of Pandas in the system default location).

`apt` does not take any virtual environments into account, it will just install in the system default location (or really: it installs files in whichever location is specified in the `.deb` package).

This immediately means that the packages *are installed*, so `rosdep` will be happy (as `apt` reports it has installed whatever `rosdep` asked of it), but the packages will *not* be available in your virtual environment.

> However, whenever I try to do pip list [..] I don't see them in the list.

this should be clear now: `pip` *will* look in your virtual environment, and as the packages have not been installed there, it will not list them as available.

---

Edit:

> is there a way of installing the dependencies in the virtual environment with a ROS tool or I need to e.g. install the dependencies manually (from e.g. a requirements.txt file)?

`rosdep` will only use `apt` on Ubuntu/Debian and `pip` for certain dependencies (typically recognisable by the `-pip` suffix on their `rosdep` key). As Python virtualen environments don't wrap/redirect `apt`, nor where `apt` installs Python modules, I would classify this as a shortcoming of how Python virtual environments work (combined with how `rosdep` prefers `apt` on Ubuntu/Debian and how Ubuntu/Debian prefers to package Python modules as `.deb` packages).

There is no way I know of that would let you list just the Python dependencies of a ROS package. You could perhaps use `rospack rosdep $pkg_name` to get a list of system dependencies (which Python pkgs typically are), somehow filter those to leave just the Python dependencies, and feed that list to the `pip` in your virtual environment.

I've never done something like that, so I have no idea how well that would work.

Providing a `requirements.txt` to your users (which would duplicate some of the dependency information from the package manifest) would certainly be convenient in cases where they'd like to use a virtual environment.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-22**:
The same 'problem' can arise with any Python interpreter other than the system default one btw. It's not unique to virtual environments.

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2019-09-22**:
Yes, you are apparently right. If I deactivate the virtual environment, I can now see the Python dependencies and import them. However, what if I did not want to pollute my global Python distribution while developing, is there a way of installing the dependencies in the virtual environment with a ROS tool or I need to e.g. install the dependencies manually (from e.g. a `requirements.txt` file)?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-22**:
just remembered there is actually a way to have `rosdep` output rules only for specific installers. You can pass it the `--filter-for-installers` option with as value `pip` for instance. This only works with the `db` command though.